# Conversion from one mathematical form to another.

Tags: analytic-geometry

I was trying to understand a solution, when a encountered this line:

$$or,\;\sum(a+\lambda l)^2=\lambda^2(l^2+m^2+n^2)\\[10pt]or,\;\lambda=-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2(al+bm+cn)}$$

I tried various method to reach the second equation from the first one, I couldn't. Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEAfw.jpg) for reference. [This is not a homework question, it's purely an evaluation based problem/technique]. I tried, taking square root and all sorts of elementary algebra techniques, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The expression $\ \sum (a+\lambda l)^2\ $ is just very lazy shorthand notation for
$$
(a+\lambda l)^2 + (b+\lambda m)^2 + (c+\lambda n)^2\ .
$$
If you expand this expression out, your second equation should fall into your lap.

Note, however, that there was a minus sign missing from the right hand side of your second equation, which I have now added.

Comment: I have done it...it starts getting too lengthy , then I get stuck.

Comment: Too lengthy?  There are only 9 terms in the expansion, and three of them are $\ \lambda^2l^2+ \lambda^2m^2+ \lambda^2n^2\ $, which cancel out those same terms on the right hand side of your first equation.